# Mock service in symfony4 command test

Tags: unit-testing, service, dependency-injection, mocking, symfony4

I have problem with command test. I am trying to mock service inside command test, but there's problem that this mock isn't used in test.

Here are command code:

```php
public function __construct(RpcClient $rpcClient, LoggerInterface $logger, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->rpcClient = $rpcClient;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

    parent::__construct();
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $apiSecurityKey = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('api_security_key');
    try {
        $apiBoxesData = $this->rpcClient->callJsonRPCPostMethod("stations_info", ["apiSecurityKey" => $apiSecurityKey]); 
.
.
.
```

And test:

```php
//some of dependencies used
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class SynchronizeBoxInfoCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{

const SYNCHRONIZE_BOX_INFO_COMMAND_NAME = "app:synchronize-box-info";

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();

    $application = new Application(static::$kernel);

    $this->command = $application->find(self::SYNCHRONIZE_BOX_INFO_COMMAND_NAME);
    $this->command->setApplication($application);
    $this->commandTester = new CommandTester($this->command);

    $this->entityManager = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $logger = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);
    $this->rpcClientMock = $this->createMock(RpcClient::class);
    $application->add(new SynchronizeBoxInfoCommand($this->rpcClientMock, $logger, $this->entityManager));

}

public function testFirstExecutionAllNewData()
{
    $this->rpcClientMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method("callJsonRPCPostMethod")
        ->willReturn(["test"]);
    $this->commandTester->execute([
        'command' => $this->command,
    ]);
}
```

For this code, when I'm running test, command when command call method `callJsonRPCPostMethod` it doesn't return mocked string "test" but it call real implementation of method, which makes call to api. I was searching whole internet and actually not find any of good answer that works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find out that adding command with mocked services to application at the end of setUp, after `$this->command = $application->find(...)` ends up with using command before mocked services. So You should declare command with mocked services before You use find command that You want to test. This code below works for me now:

```php
public function setUp()
{
    $kernel = self::bootKernel();

    $application = new Application($kernel);

    $this->entityManager = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $logger = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);
    $this->rpcClientMock = $this->createMock(RpcClient::class);
    $application->add(new SynchronizeBoxInfoCommand($this->rpcClientMock, $logger, $this->entityManager));

    $this->command = $application->find(self::SYNCHRONIZE_BOX_INFO_COMMAND_NAME);
    $this->commandTester = new CommandTester($this->command);
}
```

Comment: Indeed! The trick of "manually adding" the "manually constructed command" is the solution! Tested that this solution also works in symfony `3.3.18` when autowiring services in the command constructor.

Comment: The question is... why do we need the application and/or the kernel other than creating the infrastructure for the non-mocked services? If I do `$command = new MyNiceCommand( $myMockedService ); $commandTester = new CommandTester( $command );` it works fine instead of "adding to the application" and then "finding in the application what I created by myself". If I throw an exception in thee `configure()` I see the `commandTester` raises it, so it really calls both `configure()` and `execute()`. Would it be correct to just make a new command and test it without sending it to the application?

Comment: @XaviMontero It's a bit late for an answer but this can help someone else (this post helped me too).
It's correct to just create an instance of your command, but by adding it to the Application and finding it is also testing your command "name" (ie "app:synchronize-box-info" in this case).

As this name is maybe used by some crons or whatever else, it could be intersting to test if you don't have breaking changes on this name.

Comment: The **latest best practices** are to configure the name as a *static property* named `protected static $defaultName`  instead of via the `configure()` method. The reason is because symfony wanted to know the command names *before* instantiating them to be able to *only* instantiate the needed commands. See it here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html - Having said this, it is probably better to continue instantiating **only** the command and not the full app+kernel to test. Then if you want to test the name, get it from the command and assert it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to test such things in Symfony4.
Try to do following:

1.Make service, which you want to mock, public

2.In test mock it:

```
$this->client = static::createClient();
static::$kernel->getContainer()->set($serviceId, $serviceMock);
$application = new Application(static::$kernel);
```

3.Use this `$application` for command execution

```
$tester = (new CommandTester($application->find($commandName)))->setInputs($inputs);
$tester->execute($arguments);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it propably will work. I found out another solution based on my code. But I have question for You, is there possibility in symfony4 with dependency injection like `__construct(RpcClient $rpcClient)` to mock via set? Like: `static::$kernel->getContainer()->set(RpcClient::class, $serviceMock);`?

Comment: @PianistaMichal I suppose my solution will work in this case.